# Navigate through table TR with onkeydown or onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html

This is my current code:
Here I run some code and highlight the table row when the user clicks on the table row.

```js
$("#orders tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

  value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
});
```

```css
table {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #a0a0a0ad;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table th {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

table tr {
  height: 29px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #008cb9;
  color: #FFF;
}

#orders {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="orders" id="orders" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Betaling</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to be able to navigate through the table rows with upkey and downkey instead of clicking the table row; as well as call the method.
How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an event listner on the `keydown` then check if UP/Down keys are pressed and move the `selected` class to the next or previous `tr` :

```js
$("#orders tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.which == 38) {
    $('.selected').prev('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  } else if (e.which == 40) {
    $('.selected').next('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  }

  $('html, body').scrollTop($('.selected').offset().top - 100);

  /*$('.selected')[0].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "end"
  });*/
});
```

```css
table {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #a0a0a0ad;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table th {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

table tr {
  height: 29px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #008cb9;
  color: #FFF;
}

#orders {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="orders" id="orders" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Betaling</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='selected'>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why are u using ` if (e.which == 38)` why 38?

Comment: To know which key was clicked

Comment: Take a look to the list of keycodes http://mikemurko.com/general/jquery-keycode-cheatsheet/

Comment: Ok almost done man, how I'd be able to move the scrollbar too? I have a scrollbar and its not moving

Comment: do you want to navigate between rows when you scroll?

Comment: No when I use the keys to navigate and I have a scrollbar I want to have the scrollbar move with me

Comment: You could use `scrollIntoView()` or `$('html, body').scrollTop($('.selected').offset().top - 100);` check my update.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to achieve this.

**Step-1.** Track the `keydown` event on `document`

**Step-2.** Check for `keyCode==38(up arrow)`  and `keyCode==40(down arrow)`

**Step-3.** If true add `addClass('selected')` on `tr` and remove from `siblings()` by `removeClass('selected')`

```js
$("#orders tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.keyCode== 38) {
    $('.selected').prev('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  } else if (e.keyCode== 40) {
    $('.selected').next('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  }

});
```

```css
table {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #a0a0a0ad;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table th {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

table tr {
  height: 29px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #008cb9;
  color: #FFF;
}

#orders {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="orders" id="orders" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Betaling</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='selected'>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why and how? bro there are lot of people online on SO and this is a very common problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#orders tr").click(function() {

  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  value = $(this).find('td:first').html();

  /// my code to show data and stuff







  //////////////////////////
});

$('body').keyup(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('.selected').length == 0) {
    $($('tr')[1]).addClass('selected')
    return;
  }
  if (e.which == 38) {

    $('.selected').prev('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

  }
  if (e.which == 40) {
    $('.selected').next('tr').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

  }
})
```

```css
table {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #a0a0a0ad;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table th {
  background: #dcdcdc;
}

table tr {
  height: 29px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #008cb9;
  color: #FFF;
}

#orders {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="orders" id="orders" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Datum</th>
    <th>Betaling</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use the code as above!